# Python: How to properly modify a global variable that's already been used

Tags: python, if-statement, global

I am doing a beginner's exercise in Python.

The code asks for a name and age. If the age is higher than 100, I want to modify age_goal to 150. Any age entered above 150 will not be accepted.

```
current_year = 2017
age_goal = 100
question = "Would you like to know which year you will turn " + str(age_goal) + " years old? (Yes/No): "

user = input("What is your name?: ")
print("Hello, " + user + ".")

age = input("How old are you, " + user + "?: ")  

if int(age) > 100 and int(age) < 150:
    global age_goal
    print("Whoa, that's old!")
    age_goal = 150
elif int(age) >= 150:
    print("No one's THAT old...")
    age = input("How old are you, " + user + "?: ")
else:
    print("You are " + str(age) + " years old.")

calc = age_goal - int(age) + current_year

response = input(question)

while response != "Yes" and response != "No":
    print("Answer not accepted, try again: ")
    response = input(question)
if response == "No":
    print("That's no fun. Goodbye.")
else:
    if response == "Yes":
        print("You will be" + str(age_goal) + " years old in " + str(calc) + "!")
```

The if statement in question is listed below.

```
if int(age) > 100 and int(age) < 150:
    global age_goal
    print("Whoa, that's old!")
    age_goal = 150
```

Right now it says "name 'age_goal' is used prior to global declaration", and I understand what that means and why it's throwing that error, but I don't know how to organize the code to accept the modified global from that point on, versus trying to make it work for the code as a whole.

Comment: but `age_goal` is _already_ global. Your code isn't in a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `global` if you are already in the global namespace.  That is meant for when you want to modify a global variable inside a function.

Comment: I tried just adding "age_goal = 150" after "Whoa, that's old!", but it still uses "age_goal = 100" when asking the question and prompting user input immediately after. That's why I tried global.

Comment: I solved the issue but placing the 'question' variable after the If statement. Is that the cleanest solution? Could this be improved?

Comment: @tenneka That's because the value of `question` is fixed at the time of the assignment; Python doesn't check the current value of `age_goal` again when it *uses* the value of `question`. Put another way, the value of `question` doesn't change if you change the value of `age_goal` after the fact.

Comment: That is because you are confusing how the if branches work.  If you key in a value between 101 and 149, it will reset the age_goal to 150, but no other branches are taken.  You are probably expecting the next 'elif' to trigger, but that is not how it works.

Comment: @tenneka is correct, I re-read your question.  The problem is that you are referencing the same question that you defined only once, up top, when age_goal was 100.  If you want to get the current value, you either need to repeat that line instead of referencing it, or better, move it into a function and call the function whenever you need to get new input and compare to age_goal